# How to remove synced remote repository from vscode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm relatively new to Git and Vscode. For test purposes I created and synced a remote repository and afterwards I deleted the repository in GitHub. Now I want to sync the folder with a new repository but it does not let me. I get the following error: "Git: remote: Repository not found."

How do I delete the sync and local branches that are connecting to the deleted remote repository?

[image]

Comment: Execute `git remote ser-url origin <new repo url>` in (the directoty of) the repository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Dry run**

`git remote prune origin --dry-run`

will display all of the remotes currently assigned to the project.

**Remove**

`git remote prune origin`

If you're sure the origin is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Note that [VSCode 1.58 (June 2021)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/2f97ce730637870947c79a67060036b68fa21ff4/release-notes/v1_58.md#remote-repositories) enhances its Repositories VIew management and includes:

> you can now remove a remote repository from the `Remote Repositories` view in the Remote Explorer.

So if you do not want to use Git command, you now can remove a remote repository entirely using VSCode GUI.